# Visual Studio React template project - Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, react-hooks

I am using the React web application template in Visual Studio 2022 to create a web project.

Right after project is created, I installed a component that's implemented with hooks, e.g. React-Bootstrap by package management command -

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.1.3
```

Then I import it to home.js -

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

and add an element -

```
<div>
  <Button variant="primary">Button #1</Button>
  <Button variant="secondary" className="mx-2">Button #2</Button>
  <Button variant="success">Button #3</Button>
</div>
```

Run the project and I get the following error -

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I haven't added any other code and I think there is something wrong with the code in the template but I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: Can you share a more complete and comprehensive component code example? We can't help debug/fix code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you have VS Studio 2022 (Community version) installed, you can repro it very easily - 1. Create a React web project 2. Add a hook based component such as react-bootstrap 3. Import the component to your component 4. Add a bootstrap Button to your home app 4. Run

Comment: That may very well be, but your question still needs to include a minimal, complete, and reproducible code example. What is the generated code from using a template in Visual Studio 2022? What are the installed node packages in the package.json file?

Comment: sure - the code is at - https://github.com/adnaPzg0/ReproIssue - let me know if you can repro the issue. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/visual-studio-react-template-project-error-invalid-hook-call-jqx807) what you are expecting to see running? It's a direct import from your ClientApp sub-directory.

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected. When I start it using VS studio, I got the invalid hook call error. Did you make any changes? Can you use VS Studio to start the project and see if it runs into issues?

Comment: I imported/forked directly from your repo. There was only a missing import for something in bootstrap, which was automatically prompted, but other than that, no, I changed nothing. I don't have Visual Studio at my disposal unfortunately. How are you starting the project in VS? Is there something that actually runs the `npm start` script? If you manually run `npm start` from a terminal does it run without issue for you?

Comment: have issues start the project directly. I can do a screen sharing for troubleshooting if you are available :) Of course, use VS 2022 is the most easy way to repro my issue (see steps in the question)

Comment: How are you starting the app locally? If you run `npm start` from the project's directory in a terminal does it still have issue?

Comment: yes, exactly same issue using npm start

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the React code generated by the template was using older react 16.0 and the home.js is still a class based component.

Upgrade react and react-dom by command "npm install react" and "npm install react-dom" (upgraded to 16.14) and also change the Home.js component to be a function based component solved my problem.